# Qgis TimeManager: InvalidTimeLayerError: invalid value 'cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering'

Tags: qgis, csv, timemanager

I´m trying my first steps with Qgis and TimeManager - and getting an error right away. I have a csv file with lat/lon coordinates and a time field:

```
tour_id;action;lon;lat;time
1;move;6.9372332895695612;50.963821195552633;2019-11-15 09:46:24.26
1;move;6.9372332895695612;50.963821195552633;2019-11-15 09:46:24.26
1;move;6.9374915927437248;50.963779494857349;2019-11-15 09:46:28.01
1;move;6.9380801981505273;50.963604592683019;2019-11-15 09:46:52
1;move;6.9383692990494401;50.963562696447909;2019-11-15 09:46:58
1;move;6.9385196915956886;50.963563391256486;2019-11-15 09:47:00.029
1;move;6.9388806917567027;50.963572498665137;2019-11-15 09:47:05
1;move;6.9395207977696352;50.963601091711567;2019-11-15 09:47:12.5
...
```

I can load that without any error in Qgis, but when I add the layer in TimeManager I get this error message:

"An error occurred while trying to add layer Daten_20191115_08h35-output-tours to TimeManager. Cause: InvalidTimeLayerError: invalid value 'cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering'"

Where is my mistake? I´m using Qgis 3.4-11 Madeira and TimeManager 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly adding the layer, you have to add it through "Add Layer > Comma delimited" in your case you use "custom delimiter" and check "semicolon" (;), uncheck everything else; choose lon and lat as X and Y and finally uncheck "DMS" coordinates. If you do it right you'll see a little "point" to the left of the layer on the layers panel